# $.grep returns type void is not assignable to type boolean

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm trying to use the code below in my `TypeScript` code, but it returns an error all the time:

```
$.grep(user, function(m,i) {
    return ( n !== 5 && i > 4 );
});
```

It's `function` that get marked with:

> type void is not assignable to type boolean

Can anyone tell me why i cant do this?

Comment: You are returning Boolean value.Try to store in variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something from the function, whatever variable you need to use. First of all, I have noticed you have used n instead of m inside your returned value. Are m and i properties values of objects contained in your array? Maybe you are trying to do something similar to this:

```
$.grep(user, function(e) {
    return ( e.m !== 5 && e.i > 4 );
});
```

Hope it helps, Dino